# Implement an efficient slack-like subdomain name suggestion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a Rails app with PostgreSQL.

I'm trying to implement a method to suggest alternative names for a certain resource, if the user input has been already chosen.

My reference is slack:

[image: slack domain input]

**Is there any solution that could do this efficiently?**

For efficiently I mean: using **only one** or also **a small set of queries**. A **pure SQL solution** would be great, though.

My initial implementation looked like this:

```
def generate_alternative_names(model, column_name, count)
  words = model[column_name].split(/[,\s\-_]+/).reject(&:blank?)
  candidates = 100.times.map! { |i| generate_candidates_using_a_certain_strategy(i, words) }
  already_used = model.class.where(column_name => candidates).pluck(column_name)
  (candidates - already_used).first(count)
end

# Usage example:
model = Domain.new
model.name = 'hello-world'
generate_alternative_names(model, :name, 5)
# => ["hello_world", "hello-world2", "world_hello", ...]
```

It generates 100 candidates, then checks the database for matches and removes them from the candidates list. Finally it returns the first `count` values extracted.

This method is a **best effort implementation**, as it works for small sets of suggestions, that have few conflicts (in my case, 100 conflicts).

Even if I increase this magic number (100), it does not scales indefinitely.

Do you know a method to improve this, so it can scale for large number of conflicts and without using magic numbers?

Comment: Your method uses a single `where ... in` query. It hits the database exactly **one time**. I'm not sure what you're asking for, but if it's an off-the-shelf Gem to do this, that is off topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @meagar of course, but solution works only if conflicts are less than 100. Even if I generate more candidates, it does not scale indefinitely. I'm sure that there are better methods. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with reversed approach: query the database for existing records using [`LIKE`](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-like/) and then generate suggestions skipping already taken:

```
def alternatives(model, column, word, count)
  taken = model.class.where("#{column} LIKE '%#{word}%'").pluck(column)
  count.times.map! do |i|
    generate_candidates_using_a_certain_strategy(i, taken)
  end
end
```

Make a `generate_candidates_using_a_certain_strategy` to receive an array of already taken words to be skipped. There could be one possible glitch with race condition on two requests taking the same name, but I don’t think it might cause any problems, since you are always free to apologize when an actual creation will fail.

Comment: Interesting solution. Maybe I can improve it using a `NOT RLIKE` instead of `NOT LIKE` (using a regexp), to match more candidates to exclude (for example, allowing both `-` and `_` as separators).

Comment: Sure, this is just a headline/direction, not a complete solution.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Oh, uh, indeed :) `NOT` is superfluous.

Comment: @ProGM please see an update, I messed the things up, `LIKE` is to be used, not `NOT LIKE`, thanks for the sharp eye of Sergio.

Comment: Ya, thanks @SergioTulentsev , I didn't noticed too. :)

Comment: This also will slow down as more names are taken, but should perform much better against simple numerical suffixes ("foo1", "foo2", ..."foo12345").

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin can you specify what does function generate_candidates_using_a_certain_strategy(i, taken) do ? 
Please provide the code. I want to implement same think on Node js, so if  you can provide it javascript it will be awesome.

Comment: @David do you expect me to write the code for you in the unrelated language? Fancy.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin can you help with this or not?